# Foundation CSS conflicts with menus

Tags: html, css, menu, zurb-foundation, conflict

I'm using foundation framework for one of my projects. Also I'm using some other CSS for external menus (not by zurb foundation). But my menu css is conflicting with the foundation `large-12 columns` and producing such a result that can be seen below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCFKE.png

But when i dont take large-12 columns all goes well like below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPvPo.png

Any body got the solution so that the css dont conflicts and i get the result like in image two by using foundation large-12 columns as well.

Comment: Just investigate the conflict, and make sure your CSS overrides whatever conflicts with your module.

Comment: how to? that's what I'm unable to find

Comment: Using Firebug in Firefox, or the Chrome Developer Tools in Chrome. Just the usual frontend stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The [z-index](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) setting determines which element will appear on the top - the stacking order, set this to a value like 100 for the pop-up menu.

Inside the css add `z-index: 100` to whatever element you need on top. You didn't share code so I can't tell if you need to set `position` as well.

The css menu you are using may have documentation about stacking and `z-index` in one of the examples.